# Creating class by inheritance

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

Upon creating a class in ruby by Inheritance method does it create a new class altogether or a sort of subclass inside the class from which attributes have been inherited?

Comment: Can you clarify this? Are you saying `class B < A` and wondering what `B` looks like or something else?

Comment: I would suggest reading this [link](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html)

Comment: It creates a new class which inherits from the other class

Comment: what do you mean that classify it clearly

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby Language Specification does not prescribe any particular implementation strategy for inheritance. Every implementation is free to implement it any way it wants to.

However, considering that classes are objects just like any other object, it would extremely complex to implement them by embedding them inside of each other. Pretty much every existing Ruby implementation roughly follows this outline:

## An Object consists of an instance variable dictionary and a class pointer

```
class RubyObject
  attr_accessor :instance_variables, :klass

  def initialize(klass)
    self.klass = klass
    self.instance_variables = {}
  end
end
```

## A Module IS-A Object, and additionally has a class variable dictionary, constant dictionary, and method dictionary

```
class RubyModule < RubyObject
  attr_accessor :class_variables, :constants, :methods

  def initialize
    super(Module)
    self.class_variables = {}
    self.constants = {}
    self.methods = {}
  end
end
```

## A Class IS-A Module, and additionally has a superclass

```
class RubyClass
  attr_accessor :superclass

  def initialize(superclass)
    super()
    self.superclass = superclass
    self.klass = Class
  end
end
```